# Best way to get text of this element in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

The element that I’m talking about is the following:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr
        id="tableUsers_0__TR"
        class="active"
        name="Tr_tableUsers[0]_Selected">

        <td>
            <input
                id="tableUsers_0__POSName"
                type="hidden"
                value="Indian"
                name="tableUsers[0].POSName"/>
            Indian
        </td>
```

The solution that I propose is:

The first step is locate the element by XPath:

```python
string xpath = ".//*[@id='tableUsers_0__PDVCode']/..";
```

Then get the text with the method:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Text
```

Is it the best way? Or not?

Is there another better way than this way? Better than the use of XPath?

Comment: This is not a site to get opinions on!

Comment: This was *the* top search engine hit for *"get text of element Selenium"*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the selector `By.Id("your id")`.
2. For some elements, it’s much more useful to use `IWebElement.GetAttribute("text")` than `IWebElement.Text`

Comment: The problem here is that the text is under the balise <td> that's have Nothing as Locator(ni Id ni name ....). That's why i'm trynig to locate this Text using the balise input than the parent of this balise?!

Comment: @user3446229 I think you either use more precise xpath with /td at the end or use .Text.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript Executor can also be used to return the element's text. The following script can be used:

```javascript
document.getElementById('<your id>').innerText
```

or

```javascript
document.getElementById('<your id>').textContent
```

To get this, the object of JavascriptExecutor has to be created first. Refer to the following script:

```csharp
IWebDriver driver; // A driver object is created in the code somewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string valueFromId = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('<your id>').innerText");
```

You can also verify this text by running the JavaScript command (`document.ge`...) in the browser's console.

Comment: What is "JavaScript Executor"? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49048435/edit) a reference to it? (But ****************** ***without*** ****************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: What are the programming languages for the code snippets? Are the first two [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and the last [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a better way than using an XPath expression is to use `By.id` as:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("tableUsers_0__TR")).Text
```

Or use `By.CssSelector`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr#tableUsers_0__TR  td")).Text
```

**Note**: It always gives the last priority to the XPath locator, because it is much slower than other locators. In your case, if the element has an `id` attribute then the best way is to use `By.Id()`. Otherwise, try to locate the element using other locators, like `By.Name()`, `By.ClassName()`, `By.CssSelector()`, etc. if it could be possible.

Comment: The problem here is that the text is under the balise **<td>** that's have Nothing as Locator(ni Id ni name ....). That's why i'm trynig to locate this Text using the balise input than the parent of this balise?!

Comment: @user3446229 you are right but by locating input you can't get the text while locating tr or td you can get the text in your provided HTML because it's inside tr and td node..

Comment: If after input the text to be present any HTML tag then defenetely you can't get with using input following sibling but in your case it just text which is not present any tag but it's present tr and td tag..:)